# Create a Json array of Qstring

Tags: c++, arrays, json, qt

How to create Json array of Following Qstring and split it at \n into new line ?

```
Qstring str = "diskinfo: Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: Local Fixed Disk, FreeSpace: 418580779008, Name: C:, Size  : 499875049472  \nNode: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: CD-ROM Disc, FreeSpace: , Name: D:, Size  :   \nNode: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: Local Fixed Disk, FreeSpace: 324860469248, Name: E:, Size  : 487687450624  \nNode: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: CD-ROM Disc, FreeSpace: 0, Name: F:, Size  : 553459712"
```

I want to Convert itto Json array and each line that starts with node should be an JsonObject ? Hw can we do it in QT c++?

Tried code:

```
      QJsonObject obj_disk;
      QJsonArray  disk_array;
      obj_disk = str.split('\n')
```

Comment: what I have tried is created a QJson Object  and splited my above string at \n . now I dont know How to convert it to array?

Comment: added the code i am trying

Answer (score 4):

You can use `QJsonArray::fromStringList` to convert the returned QStringList from `str.split(...)` into a QJsonArray:

```
QJsonArray disk_array = QJsonArray::fromStringList(str.split('\n'));
```